# Input taking spaces by default in c

Tags: c

In the below program when am reading input from keyboard its taking only 2 characters instead of 4 and remaining 2 characters its taking spaces by default.
why is it???

*program to take char input through pointers*/

```
int c,inc,arrysize;
char *revstring;
printf("enter the size of char arry:");
scanf("%d",&arrysize);
revstring = (char *)malloc(arrysize * sizeof(*revstring));
printf("%d",sizeof(revstring));
printf("enter the array elements:");
for(inc=0;inc<arrysize;inc++)
{
scanf("%c",&revstring[inc]);

}
for(inc =0;inc<arrysize;inc++)
    printf("%c",revstring[inc]);
getch();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` reads formatted inputs. When you tape a number, you tape the digits, and then, you press `<Enter>`. So there is a remaining `\n` in `stdin`, which is read in the next `scanf`. The same applies if you press `<Enter>` between the characters.

A solution is to consume the characters in the standard input stream after each input, as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
clean_stdin (void)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    ;
}
```

Another idea is to use `fgets` to get human inputs. `scanf` is not suitable for such readings.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time `scanf` reads formatted input.  For most `%` formats, scanf will first read and discard any whitespace and then parse the item specified.  So with `scanf("%d", ...` it will accept inputs with initial spaces (or even extra newlines!) with no problems.

One of the exceptions, however, is `%c`.  With `%c`, scanf reads the very next character, whatever it may be.  If that next character is a space or newline, that is what you get.

Depending on what exactly you want, you may be able to just use a blank space in your format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&revstring[inc]);
```

The space causes `scanf` to skip any whitespace in the input, giving you the next non-whitespace character read.  However, this will make it impossible to enter a string with spaces in it (the spaces will be ignored).  Alternately, you could do `scanf(" ");` before the loop to skip whitespace once, or `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");` to skip everything up to the next newline, and then skip the newline.